# Creating directories with spaces using awk and mkdir

Tags: bash, awk

I'm writing a bash script to create folders with spaces in there name by using the output of awk.

```
getAuthors() {
    echo "$1" | awk -F ', |, and |and ' '{ for (i =1; i<=NF; i++) system("mkdir "$i" ") }'
}
```

This function will take in a string along the lines of "Sokratis Katsikas and Isaac Agudo (eds.)". I'm grabbing all the authors from pdf's and have to split them based on the regex that I created for the awk field separator. However when I try to make the call to mkdir to create folders for each separate author it tries to make a directory for each separate word. eg. For the example string I'm using, it will split Sokratis Katsikas from Isaac Agudo (eds.) but mkdir will attempt to create individual folders for Sokratis, Katsika, Isaac, and Agudo. How do I make it so the call to mkdir preserves the spaces instead of trying to create folders for each word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your `system` function with additional quotes:

```
system("mkdir \"" $i "\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a sed command which changes space to \space.

Comment: I'm really new to bash scripting so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: sed -i 's/ /\\ /' filename